# ValueError: Two-way partial dependence plots are not supported for pairs of continuous and categorical features

Tags: pdp

I am trying to get a two way `pdp` plot for pairs of continuous, and categorical features in Python.

But I get this error:ValueError:

```
Two-way partial dependence plots are not supported for pairs of continuous and categorical features.
```

My model is `LGBM`.
and below is my code. Any advise?

```
model= lgb.LGBMRegressor(learning_rate=0.05)

model.fit(X,Y)

fig

pdp_display = PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(
    model, 
    X, 
    [('categorical_feature', 'quantitative_feature')],  
    categorical_features = categorical_features_Boolean,
    grid_resolution=50,
)

plt.show
```

I prefer avoiding encoding my categorical variables as they have high cardinality.

I am expecting a two way `pdp` plot for pairs of continuous and categorical features.

But I get this error:ValueError:

```
Two-way partial dependence plots are not supported for pairs of continuous and categorical features.
```

It works well when my pairs are the same type. But when they are not the same, I get the error.Any advise?